# How to create collections dynamically in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have huge record to store for each company, one company can contain 200k records. how can we create a dynamic collection for each company with company name to avoid filtration in mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

From mongo docs here: data modeling

In certain situations, you might choose to store information in
several collections rather than in a single collection.

Consider a sample collection logs that stores log documents for various environment and applications. The logs collection contains
documents of the following form:

{ log: "dev", ts: ..., info: ... } { log: "debug", ts: ..., info: ...}
 If the total number of documents is low you may group documents into
collection by type. For logs, consider maintaining distinct log
collections, such as logs.dev and logs.debug. The logs.dev collection
would contain only the documents related to the dev environment.
 Generally, having large number of collections has no significant
 performance penalty and results in very good performance. Distinct
collections are very important for high-throughput batch processing.